# EmailJs is not sending email by React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, html-email, mern

I hope you are doing great, I am using Emailjs in React to get Emails. I configure Emailjs and it is properly sending test Emails but when I am trying to send from my project so it's not sending and even it is also not showing any error

Here is the template of the Email
[image]

Here is the ID and token which I hide but I am just showing this image to explain
clearly
[image]

(1) Here i import emailjs

```
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';
```

(2) Here is the function that will send the email, (Here in the fourth parameter I am just showing 5 characters as I hide in the above image )

```
function sendEmail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    emailjs.send('gmail', 'zaryabkhan864', e.target, 'G5CpT9*******')
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result.text);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error.text);
        });
    e.target.reset()
}
```

(3) Here is the Form code

```
<form onSubmit={sendEmail}>
<div className="mb-3">
<label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">Your Name</label>
<input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Muhammad Zaryab Khan" name="name" />
</div>
<div className="mb-3">
<label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">Email address</label>
<input type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com" name="email" />
</div>
<div className="mb-3">
<label htmlFor="exampleFormControlTextarea1" className="form-label">Your Message</label>
<textarea className="form-control" id="Message" rows="5" name="message"></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" className="btn-theme">Send Message <i className="fa fa-paper-plane ms-2"></i></button>
</form>
```

Now I am receiving this error

[image]

Comment: According to the author, This library has been deprecated.
Try using their new official SDK for browser: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emailjs/browser
I haven't used this library. I hope this helps.

Comment: I follow that link you mentioned so i am going to update my question kindly recheck it

Comment: Kindly check it again @usman-pervaiz

Answer (score 0):

add ref atribute for form, and ad useRef

`const form = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);`

after you should change e.target => form.current

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
const form = useRef();
    
const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
        
    emailjs.sendForm('service_id', 'template_id', form.current, 'user_id')
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.text);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error.text);
    });
    alert("Email Send");
};
```

Comment: const form inside form tag exp => <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `useRef()` like other comments have suggested, you could use `useState()` to store the values in the form fields and pass them into emailjs `send()` [method](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/sdk/send/).

Example:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";

export const Component = () => {
  // Create Form State
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    message: "",
    email: "",
  });

  // Handle Submit
  function sendEmail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    emailjs.send("gmail", "zaryabkhan864", formData, "G5CpT9*******").then(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result.text);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error.text);
      }
    );
    e.target.reset();
  }
};
```

I'd also suggest you to use a `.env` to store your environment variables. Because you don't want to be exposing these values for security reasons.

Example:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";

export const Component = () => {
  // Create Form State
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    message: "",
    email: "",
  });

  // Handle Submit
  function sendEmail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    emailjs
      .send(
        import.meta.env.EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID,
        import.meta.env.EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID,
        formData,
        import.meta.env.EMAILJS_PUBLIC_KEY
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
    e.target.reset();
  }
};
```

and your `.env` file should look something like:

```
EMAILJS_PUBLIC_KEY=public_key_value
EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID=template_id_value
EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID=service_id_value
```